# Get the last updated folder in HDFS

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hadoop, hdfs

I want the latest updated folder from one of my HDFS directories.I was able to get the latest file in hdfs file system but not sure how to do it for HDFS one.I tried with shell script.

Comment: How did you get the latest file? You can use the same script for folder also.

Comment: hadoop fs -ls -R /tmp/app | awk -F" " '{print $6" "$7" "$8}' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -d" " -f3

Comment: The solution in the answers section is similar. Try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Hadoop 2.6, I could get it work with the following command:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R ${DIR} | grep "^d" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8
```

where,

`hdfs dfs -ls -R ${DIR}` : gives all dirs recursively

`grep "^d"` : gives only directories

`sort -k6,7` : sorts them by modification time

`tail -1` : gives listing for last modified directory

`tr -s ' '` : some formatting

`cut -d' ' -f8` : gives only directory path

**Example:**

```
[user@nodeX]$ hdfs dfs -ls -R /tmp/a 
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2017-08-08 03:08 /tmp/a/b
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2017-08-08 03:11 /tmp/a/b/c
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2017-08-08 03:12 /tmp/a/b/c/CC
-rw-r--r--   3 hduser supergroup          0 2017-08-08 03:12 /tmp/a/b/c/CC/f2.txt
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2017-08-08 03:08 /tmp/a/b/c/d
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2017-08-08 03:08 /tmp/a/b/c/d/e
-rw-r--r--   3 hduser supergroup          6 2017-08-08 03:10 /tmp/a/b/c/f1.txt
```

**Solution:**

```
[user@nodeX]$ hdfs dfs -ls -R /tmp/a | grep "^d" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8

/tmp/a/b/c/CC
```